# Is Atom IDE proprietary?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, atom

While searching most suitable IDE for coding, I've encountered on [Atom](https://atom.io/). So in order to test it - downloaded `.deb` and opened it in software center.

But software center states it has **proprietary** license.

[image: Atom listed as proprietary]

Being really averse to all proprietary I've checked atom info again. And it is in opposite states Atom is open software with code opened on [GitHub](https://github.com/atom/atom). License is [MIT](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/LICENSE.md) which allows all of permissions like

- Commercial use
- Modification
- Distribution
- Private use

So why is it marked as **proprietary**?

Comment: I see. It's really looks like a bug for apps with "Other Open Source" license. But as for atom - it's "truly" open source, and there is no 'underwater rocks', right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atom text editor is a native Ubuntu snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Results of `snap info atom`:

```
$ snap info atom
name:      atom
summary:   A hackable text editor for the 21st Century.

Atom is a free and open source text editor that is modern, approachable,  
and hackable to the core.
```

The Ubuntu Atom snap package does not have a proprietary license. The [Atom GitHub webpage](https://github.com/atom) also describes Atom as a free and open source text editor. Atom is licensed under the
[MIT License](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/LICENSE.md).

The atom-amd64.deb file has a file in it named *copyright* which contains a copy of the MIT License terms, yet when atom-amd64.deb is opened in the Ubuntu Software app it is mistakenly reported as having a proprietary license.

If Ubuntu Software is reporting the MIT license as a proprietary license this is a bug in Ubuntu Software, because the MIT license is a free software license. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License), the MIT License is a permissive free software license originating at the Massachusetts Institute of Technology (MIT). The MIT license permits reuse within proprietary software provided that all copies of the licensed software include a copy of the MIT License terms and the copyright notice.